# Where is the war file built in Intellij IDEA, located?

Tags: intellij-idea, deployment, jboss, war, wildfly

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and I'm building and deploying the web-application project every time I'm running it. All of this happens magically within IntelliJ IDEA.

However, now I'm supposed to manually deploy it on a test server's wildfly, so I need an artifact file (WAR or EAR) to drop in the standalone/deployments directory on the test server's running WildFly10.

I can't for the life of me find where IntelliJ Idea exports the WAR / EAR artifacts so I could copy paste it to the said directory on the test server. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow the steps :

1. Click on Edit Configurations.
2. Click on Deployment and add your artifact.
3. Apply these changes.
4. You can see a Build Artifacts under Build.
5. Click on Build Artifacts and it will create a war/jar to the respective folder.

If I'm wrong somewhere let me know.